# ParentId on Child Record

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list

Ahhh Salesforce, here we go...

When creating a new Opportunity record using the Account's related list New Opportunity button, I am able to get the Account Id using "Map m = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters('accid');" and query for other Account data in the OpportunityExtension class and display it on a new Opportunity record before it is saved for the first time.

I would like to do this on other child objects as well.

I have created a child object (Cost Estimate Request) of Opportunity thru a lookup field.

How do I get Opportunity's (related list) "New Cost Estimate Request" button to include the Opportunity Id in the parameters, so that I can query for other Opportunity data to display on the child object, like I did on Opportunity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce automatically provides this value to the page via the StandardController on page overrides. You probably won't see it in the URL, but the page does know that the opportunity field should have this Id populated. You can grab the record from the StandardController and check your lookup field, and it should have the value populated already.

Edit:

Here's live code from a developer org I use to test code for SFSE, which has the objects Parent__c and Child__c. It demonstrates how I can tell what the value of Parent__c is both in the page and the page's controller.

Controller:

```
public class newChildExtension {
    public newChildExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Parent record ID is '+((Child__c)controller.getRecord()).Parent__c));
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Child__c" extensions="newChildExtension">
    Parent__c record ID is {!Child__c.Parent__c}.
    <apex:pageMessages />
</apex:page>
```

This is provided automatically, without any additional code. From here, all I did was override the "New Child" button, and this functionality was provided for free.

Comment: I am trying to display this information on the NEW child page, before it is saved. How do I access the Opportunity Id from this child object prior to having saved the child object record?

Comment: @Tim See my example code. Try it out. It *really* is that easy.

Comment: Thanks fox, that was really easy. Very much appreciated!!!